# Find index number of json by its key

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

say if I have a json object like:

```
{
  "items":[
      {"key_1": "value 1"},
      {"key_2": "value 2"},
      {"key_3": "value 3"},
      {"key_4": "value 4"},
      {"key_5": "value 5"},
      {"key_6": "value 6"},
      {"key_7": "value 7"},
      {"key_8": "value 8"}
  ]
}
```

is there a way for me to get which index is that key_id that i provided:

```
key = "key_3";
index_number = find index of key;
```

Comment: Iterate over the array with a `for` loop and check whether they key is in the object. If yes, break the loop. The current value of the loop variable is the index.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
var obj = {
  "items":[
      {"key_1": "value 1"},
      {"key_2": "value 2"},
      {"key_3": "value 3"},
      {"key_4": "value 4"},
      {"key_5": "value 5"},
      {"key_6": "value 6"},
      {"key_7": "value 7"},
      {"key_8": "value 8"}
  ]
};

function getIndexOfKey(key){
    for (var i = 0; i < obj.items.length; i++)
    {
        if (typeof(obj.items[i][key]) != 'undefined')
        {
            return i;
        }
    }    
    return -1;
}
```

You can see it in action here : http://jsfiddle.net/GTXBU/

Comment: Note that it wont work if the `key`entry is the empty string, or 0. You should use `typeof(obj.items[i][key]) != 'undefined'`.

Comment: It actually works, at least in my browser :). check this : http://jsfiddle.net/GTXBU/1/

Comment: @andri: The problem is not when the key is `0`, but when the property *value* is `0`, `false`, etc.

Comment: @andri Try this with your code `{"items":[{"key_1": 0},{"key_2": ""}]}`.

Comment: sorry for my mistake understanding @ClementBellot's comment. Updated to include the fix.

Answer (score 0):

You can try some thing like this:

```
var obj = {
"items":[
  {"key_1": "value 1"},
  {"key_2": "value 2"},
  {"key_3": "value 3"},
  {"key_4": "value 4"},
  {"key_5": "value 5"},
  {"key_6": "value 6"},
  {"key_7": "value 7"},
  {"key_8": "value 8"}
  ]
}
var key = "key_3";
for(var index in str.items){
if(str.items[index][key]!=undefined) break;
}
console.log(index);
```